# Where'd this layout come from?

Tags: thesis, books, formatting

In the past, I experimented a lot with the layout of my thesis. Until I managed to find a PDF of a standard book layout of some publisher, which attracted me so much that I copied it for my thesis.

[image]

The problem is: I can't remember where I got this layout from. Does anyone have an idea? It was the standard layout example of some publisher ...

Thanks!

Comment: One thing to consider is that your love of a layout does not trump the requirements of your institution. Some of us remember the dreaded 'thesis secretary' who had a sharp eye and a steel ruler and could refuse to accept your thesis until it met the typographic standards (nominally required by the thesis microfiche houses).

Comment: It is Latex. Your Latex compiler generated it, the answer lies probably somewhere in its deep internals.

Comment: Arrgh. It's made in Word.

Comment: @JonCuster I figured someone would bring that up. In fact, the Dean's Office of our faculty collects the theses; they will get an ugly copy which is conform the guidelines, and my (co-)promotors will get a more beautiful version.

Comment: @user153812 Why wouldn't it be legal?  At every university I've ever heard of, the author of the dissertation owns the copyright, not the university.

Comment: @JeffE- You're right about the legality, I withdraw the comment.

Comment: Indeed. Dean's Office stated that the supervisor is the final responsible editor and he gets to decide. And he agreed. My supervisor and I own the copyright for the dissertation; university holds the rights for the results of the studies.

Comment: So… is it in Latex or with other word-processing software? In the first case, you may want to check https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227348/34551 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252106/34551

Comment: I replicated this in Microsoft Office. I'm not sure how the original publishers made it ...

Comment: Du you still have the original file? What was your source?
Maybe your browsing history (´strg + H´ in most browsers) could help as well...

Comment: I'm afraid not ... The fonts that were used in the original was Myriad Pro (titles, authors and affiliations) and Warnock Pro (body text)